# Dynamic JSF/Primefaces poor loading

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, mojarra

My project is a dynamic report app similar to JasperReport and am using JSF 2.2.7 (Mojara) and primefaces 5.0. When a user logs in, he/she sees just the reports assigned to him/her which is dynamically loaded from the database. Everything else is working properly except that when they select a report, the page doesnt load the entire report until a second click.

My problem is the report doesnt load properly until a second click. Here are my code.

```
@Named(value = "userController")
@SessionScoped
public class ReportUserController implements Serializable {

private HtmlPanelGroup panelGroup;  // with getter and setter

@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    values = new ArrayList<>();
    // Retrieve user's details and reports here

    MenuModel model = new DefaultMenuModel();
    Application application = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getApplication();
    panelGroup = (HtmlPanelGroup) application.createComponent(HtmlPanelGroup.COMPONENT_TYPE);
    PanelGrid panelGrid = (PanelGrid) application.createComponent(PanelGrid.COMPONENT_TYPE);
    panelGrid.setColumns(2);

    // Retrieve reports for d group the logged-in user belong
    List<Report> repts = setupController.getExistingReports();

    DefaultSubMenu reports = new DefaultSubMenu("Reports");
    for (Report rep : repts) {
        DefaultMenuItem menuItem = new DefaultMenuItem(rep.getReportName());
        menuItem.setId(rep.getReportName().replaceAll("\\s+", "")); 
        menuItem.setAjax(true);
        menuItem.setUpdate(":reportForm");
        menuItem.setProcess("@form");
        menuItem.setCommand("#{userController.loadReport(" + rep.getId() + ")}");
        reports.addElement(menuItem);
        reports.addElement(new DefaultSeparator());

    }
    model.addElement(reports);
    Menubar menubar = (Menubar) application.createComponent(Menubar.COMPONENT_TYPE);
    menubar.setModel(model);

    panelGroup.getChildren().add(menubar);

}

public void loadReport(Long id) {

    selectedReport = reportFacade.find(id);
    if (parameters != null) {
        parameters.clear();
    }

    if (values != null) {
        values.clear();
    }

    queryColumns = selectedReport.getColumns();

    queryParams = selectedReport.getReportParameters();
    query = selectedReport.getReportQuery();

    // This method is called to build the components of the page to be rendered dynamically.
    // And it's every time a new report is selected
    buildPage();

}

}
```

And here is the `buildPage()` method in the same class. (Please bear with me its a stupidly long code)

```
    public void buildPage() {

    Application application = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getApplication();
    reportPanelGroup = (HtmlPanelGroup)    application.createComponent(HtmlPanelGroup.COMPONENT_TYPE);
    PanelGrid panelGrid = (PanelGrid) application.createComponent(PanelGrid.COMPONENT_TYPE);
    panelGrid.setColumns(2);

    for (ReportParameter param : queryParams) {

        String parameterLabel = param.getLabel();
        String componentType = param.getComponentType();
        String calendarPattern = param.getCalendarPattern();
        boolean required = param.isRequired();
        boolean userProperty = param.isUserProperty();
        String queryPosition = param.getQueryPosition();
        String sqlDatePattern = param.getSqlDatePattern();
        String dataType = param.getDataType();
        String userPropertyName = param.getUserPropertyName();
        List<DropDown> dropDowns = param.getDropDowns();

        if ((userProperty)) {
            // Retrieve some info from the logged-in user              
        } else {

            OutputLabel label = (OutputLabel) application.createComponent(OutputLabel.COMPONENT_TYPE);

            label.setId(parameterLabel.replaceAll("\\s+", "") + "label");
            label.setValue(parameterLabel + ":");

            if (componentType.equalsIgnoreCase("Calendar")) {
                Calendar cal = (Calendar) application.createComponent(Calendar.COMPONENT_TYPE);

                cal.setId(parameterLabel.replaceAll("\\s+", ""));
                cal.setShowButtonPanel(true);
                cal.setPattern(calendarPattern);
                cal.setRequired(required);

                cal.setValueExpression("value",
                        getExpressionFactory()
                        .createValueExpression(getELContext(), "#{userController.parameters['"
                                + queryPosition.trim() + "']}", Date.class));

                label.setFor(parameterLabel.replaceAll("\\s+", ""));
                panelGrid.getChildren().add(label);

                panelGrid.getChildren().add(cal);

            } else if (componentType.equalsIgnoreCase("TextField")) {
                InputText input = (InputText) application.createComponent(InputText.COMPONENT_TYPE);
                input.setRequired(required);
                input.setId(parameterLabel.replaceAll("\\s+", ""));

                input.setValueExpression("value",
                        getExpressionFactory()
                        .createValueExpression(getELContext(), "#{userController.parameters['"
                                + queryPosition.trim() + "']}", String.class));

                label.setFor(parameterLabel.replaceAll("\\s+", ""));
                panelGrid.getChildren().add(label);

                panelGrid.getChildren().add(input);
            } else if (componentType.equalsIgnoreCase("DropDown")) {

                SelectOneMenu selectOneMenu = (SelectOneMenu) application.createComponent(SelectOneMenu.COMPONENT_TYPE);
                UISelectItems selectItems = (UISelectItems) application.createComponent(UISelectItems.COMPONENT_TYPE);
                selectOneMenu.setRequired(required);
                selectOneMenu.setId(parameterLabel.replaceAll("\\s+", ""));

                selectItems.setId(parameterLabel.replaceAll("\\s+", "") + "selectItems");

                List<SelectItem> items = new ArrayList<>();

                items.add(new SelectItem("", "Select..."));
                if (dropDowns != null && !dropDowns.isEmpty()) {
                    for (DropDown d : dropDowns) {
                        items.add(new SelectItem(d.getValue(), d.getLabel()));
                    }
                }

                selectItems.setValue(items);
                selectOneMenu.getChildren().add(selectItems);

                selectOneMenu.setValueExpression("value",
                        getExpressionFactory()
                        .createValueExpression(getELContext(), "#{userController.parameters['"
                                + queryPosition.trim() + "']}", String.class));

                label.setFor(parameterLabel.replaceAll("\\s+", ""));
                panelGrid.getChildren().add(label);

                panelGrid.getChildren().add(selectOneMenu);

            }
        }
    }
    reportPanelGroup.getChildren().add(panelGrid);

    HtmlCommandButton searchBtn = (HtmlCommandButton) application.createComponent(HtmlCommandButton.COMPONENT_TYPE);
    searchBtn.setId("searchBtnID");
    searchBtn.setValue("Search");
    //searchBtn.setIcon("icon ui-icon-search");
    //searchBtn.setAjax(false);

    ExpressionFactory ef = getApplication().getExpressionFactory();
    MethodExpression performSearch = ef.createMethodExpression(getELContext(),
            "#{userController.performSearch}", null, new Class[]{ActionEvent.class});
    MethodExpressionActionListener meal = new MethodExpressionActionListener(performSearch);
    searchBtn.addActionListener(meal);
    searchBtn.setType("submit");

    //searchForm.getChildren().add(searchBtn);
    reportPanelGroup.getChildren().add(searchBtn);

    Spacer spacer = (Spacer) application.createComponent(Spacer.COMPONENT_TYPE);
    spacer.setHeight("30");
    reportPanelGroup.getChildren().add(spacer);

    HtmlForm downloadForm = (HtmlForm) application.createComponent(HtmlForm.COMPONENT_TYPE);
    downloadForm.setId("downloadForm");

    CommandLink downloadBtn = (CommandLink) application.createComponent(CommandLink.COMPONENT_TYPE);
    downloadBtn.setId("downloadBtnID");
    downloadBtn.setValue("Test Download");
    //downloadBtn.setIcon("icon ui-icon-search");
    downloadBtn.setAjax(false);

    String reportName = this.selectedReport.getReportName().trim().replaceAll("\\s+", "").trim();

    MethodExpression downloadAnyReport = ef.createMethodExpression(getELContext(),
            "#{userController.downloadAnyReport(userController.values, "
            + "userController.headings, '" + reportName + "')}", null, // Replace report name
            new Class[]{List.class, Collection.class, String.class});
    downloadBtn.setType("submit");
    downloadBtn.setActionExpression(downloadAnyReport);

    downloadForm.getChildren().add(downloadBtn);
    reportPanelGroup.getChildren().add(downloadForm);

    DataTable dynamicTable = (DataTable) application.createComponent(DataTable.COMPONENT_TYPE);
    dynamicTable.setValueExpression("value", getExpressionFactory()
            .createValueExpression(getELContext(), "#{userController.values}", List.class));
    dynamicTable.setVar("val");
    dynamicTable.setRows(20);

    List cols = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < queryColumns.size(); i++) {
        Column col = (Column) application.createComponent(Column.COMPONENT_TYPE);
        col.setHeaderText(queryColumns.get(i).getPrefferedName());
        if (queryColumns.get(i).isLink()) {
            HtmlForm linkForm = (HtmlForm) application.createComponent(HtmlForm.COMPONENT_TYPE);
            linkForm.setId("linkForm");
            CommandLink link = (CommandLink)     application.createComponent(CommandLink.COMPONENT_TYPE);

            if (queryColumns.get(i).isDataMasked()) {
                link.setValueExpression("value", getExpressionFactory().createValueExpression(getELContext(),
                        "#{userController.maskStringValue(val[" + i + "]," + queryColumns.get(i).getLeftDigit() + "," + queryColumns.get(i).getRightDigit() + ")}", String.class));
            } else {
                link.setValueExpression("value", getExpressionFactory().createValueExpression(getELContext(),
                        "#{val[" + i + "]}", String.class));
            }

            link.setStyle("text-decoration: underline; color: blue;");
            MethodExpression action = ef.createMethodExpression(getELContext(),
                    "customizeColumns?faces-redirect=true", null, new Class[]{String.class});
            link.setAjax(false);
            link.setActionExpression(action);
            linkForm.getChildren().add(link);
            col.getChildren().add(linkForm);
        } else {
            HtmlOutputText out = (HtmlOutputText) application.createComponent(HtmlOutputText.COMPONENT_TYPE);
            if (queryColumns.get(i).getFormatAs() != null && queryColumns.get(i).getFormatAs().equals("Amount")) {
                out.setValueExpression("value", getExpressionFactory().createValueExpression(getELContext(),
                        "#{userController.formatAsAmount(val[" + i + "])}", String.class));
            } else if (queryColumns.get(i).getFormatAs() != null && queryColumns.get(i).getFormatAs().equals("Number")) {
                out.setValueExpression("value", getExpressionFactory().createValueExpression(getELContext(),
                        "#{userController.formatAsNumber(val[" + i + "])}", String.class));
            } else if (queryColumns.get(i).isDataMasked()) {
                out.setValueExpression("value", getExpressionFactory().createValueExpression(getELContext(),
                        "#{userController.maskStringValue(val[" + i + "]," + queryColumns.get(i).getLeftDigit() + "," + queryColumns.get(i).getRightDigit() + ")}", String.class));
            } else {
                out.setValueExpression("value", getExpressionFactory().createValueExpression(getELContext(),
                        "#{val[" + i + "]}", String.class));
            }

            col.getChildren().add(out);
        }
        cols.add(col);
    }

    dynamicTable.setColumns(cols); //renderReport
    dynamicTable.setValueExpression("rendered", getExpressionFactory()
            .createValueExpression(getELContext(), "#{userController.values.size() > 0}",     Boolean.class));

    dynamicTable.setPaginator(true);
    dynamicTable.setRowsPerPageTemplate("20,50,100");

    reportPanelGroup.getChildren().add(dynamicTable);

}
```

And here is my page:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
 <!DOCTYPE composition PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
 <ui:composition xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
            template="./usersTemplate.xhtml"
            xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
            xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<ui:define name="usersTitle">
    usersTitle
</ui:define>

<ui:define name="usersContent">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <p:growl id="growl" life="3000" sticky="true"/>
        <h:form id="menuForm">
            <!-- This panelGroup is for the menubar of reports -->
            <h:panelGroup binding="#{userController.panelGroup}"/>
        </h:form>
        <h:form id="reportForm"> 
            <!-- This panelGroup is to show the components and datatable of the selected report -->              
            <h:panelGroup id="reportPanel" binding="#{userController.reportPanelGroup}"/>
        </h:form>
    </div>
</ui:define>
```

Please let me say it again, everything else is working fine except that when i select a report from the list of reports in the menubar, the page is not updated until a second click and i tried both full page submission as well as Ajax. Please i will greatly appreciate any help one can sugest. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

For other persons that might have similar problem in the future, lemme post the solution i eventually settled for which is working perfectly. I added a `<p:commandButton/>` to the page with `rendered` attribute toggled with the selected report's components. Then  i added a javascript method to fire a click of the `commandButton` after the `ajax` call through the `oncomplete` attribute of the `menuItems` in the `menubar`. Here are the code snipets:

`// JavaScript:`

```
  function clickAgain(){
        document.getElementById('reportForm:refreshBtn').click();
    }
```

`// I added the button to my page:`

`...`

```
<h:form id="reportForm">
            <p:commandButton value=" Load #{userController.selectedReport.reportName}"
                             icon="ui-icon-refresh" rendered="#{!userController.renderReport}"
                             id="refreshBtn">
                <p:ajax update="@form" listener="#{userController.changeRender()}"/>
            </p:commandButton>
            <h:panelGroup id="reportPanel" binding="#{userController.reportPanelGroup}"
                          rendered="#{userController.renderReport}"/>
 </h:form>
```

The magic is the user never sees the button, the javascript function is called after every selection of the menuitem and this reloads the page making the button disappear and my report load properly. Thanks